# zsh gnu-screen tab completion for `-x` flag similar to `-ls`

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

In bash, when I type `screen -x` and press tab twice, I get a list of all the running sessions.

In zsh, when I type `screen -ls` and press tab twice, I get a list of all the running sessions and can tab through them, eventually select one when pressing enter, but this then executes `screen -ls session-name` when pressing enter again.

What I want in zsh is to get a behavior for `-x` similar to `-ls`, so that I don't have to type the session name or select the session and go back and change `ls` to `x`.

I can't find the code which implements the `screen -ln` tab-behavior in order to also implement it for `-x`, I've been searching/grepping through the list of `.oh-my-zsh` plugins but am getting nowhere.

Any help is appreciated, or maybe some workflow tips. I use screen a lot and most of it is via `screen -x`.

Comment: `screen -x`TAB in zsh should list the attached screen sessions, while `screen -ls`TAB should list all screen sessions whether they're attached or not.

Comment: You can always do `screen -x -S <Tab>` to complete any screen session with -x, or modify a copy of the `_screen` file to change the behaviour.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, very interesting the fact about that it lists already attached screens. I just checked and indeed that is the behavior. How can I change that?

Comment: Also thanks for the `screen -x -S <Tab>` workaround, works just like what I'm after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is in [`_screen`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Command/_screen) (completion is provided natively by zsh, it's not an additional plugin). Zsh completes all sessions for `-ls` but only attached sessions for `-x`.

`-x` is intended to “Attach to a not detached screen session” (per the manual). But it also works if the session is detached. So both behaviors make sense. Ideally, this should be a configuration option for zsh's completion.

To get the behavior you want instead of the current behavior, you need to change the line

```
  '-x[attach to a not detached screen (multi display mode)]: :->attached-sessions' \
```

to

```
  '-x[attach to a not detached screen (multi display mode)]: :->any-sessions' \
```

Here's some code you can put in your init file to monkey-patch the completion function to get the behavior you want. It needs to go after `compinit` (so after the oh-my-zsh lines if you use oh-my-zsh).

```
# Monkey-patch the screen completion function to complete all sessions
# after -x, not just detached sessions.
autoload +X _screen # load immediately
set -o extendedglob # needed for (#b) and # below and generally a good
                    # thing to have in interactive shells
functions[_screen]=${functions[_screen]/(#b)(\'-x[^:]#:[^:]#:->)attached-sessions(\')/${match[1]}any-sessions${match[2]}}
```